# C++ program using the haskell compiler when it errors in vs code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cross-compiling

When I have the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct Card
{
    enum suit {CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES};
    suit Suit;
    int rank; 
};

class Deck 
{
    queue<Card> deck;

public:
    //create the deck of cards
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j <= 13; j++)
        {
            Card temp = {i, j}
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::cout < "Hello\n";

}
```

This contains some errors which isn't the problem. The problem is the error messages I get. The first part is understandable:

```
> Executing task: g++ -g main.cpp <

main.cpp:19:5: error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'
     for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
     ^~~
main.cpp:19:20: error: 'i' does not name a type
     for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                    ^
main.cpp:19:28: error: 'i' does not name a type
     for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
                        ^
```

The second part however looks like it tried to compile the code with the Haskell compiler.

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:15: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 
'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'const char [7]')
     std::cout < "Hello\n";
     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/ios:40,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/iostream:39,
                 from main.cpp:1:
C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:369:5: note: 
candidate: template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool 
std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
     ^~~~~~~~
```

This goes on for a while, since a c++ program isn't exactly valid Haskell code. I would like to know how to resolve this issue, since it makes debugging a big problem. I'm using VSCode and while I could share my c_cpp_properties.json file I'm already sure I got that right and I don't want to make the question even longer.

Comment: You can't write code in the middle of a C++ class. Perhaps you want a `Deck` constructor. (Why this is tagged Haskell?)

Comment: There is no [haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) involved in the question at all - apart from being mentioned...

Comment: `public:
    //create the deck of cards
    for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) ` - ehh, no. There needs to be a function there.

Comment: I'm new in c++, alright. The code isn't the problem, the error-message is.

Comment: After you get the missing function bit worked out, I recommend checking the range of possible values allowed here `for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) ` and here `for(int j = 0; j <= 13; j++)`

Comment: Hate to be a nag, Trashtalk, but the error message is the result of the code.

Comment: Looks like c++ compiler to me. It just says that there's an error in a file that happens to be in Haskell directory. Why they put those files there is not relevant. The error is actually in your code(`std::cout < "Hello";` should be `std::cout <<"Hello";`) but thanks to templates you get nice and long error mesage in those "Haskell" files.

Comment: Basically, you said that you want to compare `std::cout` which is `std::ostream` object and a `char*`(string). So the compiler goes on and searches for an operator< that matches that description. The second line of the error says it did not find any. But then also points out that there are two `std::operator<` functions that are similiar, you know maybe you just made a typo. And it happens that those two operators are located in Haskell directory.

Comment: @Quimby At this point you've put together enough in those two comments for a reasonable and informative answer. Might as well formally write it up.

Comment: Thank you Quimby, it's good to know that there is no magic going on. I should just trust the compiler next time.

Comment: @user4581301 Good idea, done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is c++ compiler, not Haskell's. 
As others pointed out in comments, you cannot put for loop (or any executable code for that matter) in class definition.

**Let's try to understand the second error message:**

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:31:15: error: no match for 'operator<' (operand types are 
'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}' and 'const char [7]')
     std::cout < "Hello\n";
     ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~
```

By writing `std::cout < "Hello\n";` you said that you want to compare `std::cout` which is an `std::ostream` object with `const char [7]`(string). The compiler told you that it does not know how to do that. Because formally you asked for an `operator<` function and it did not find it.

But it did find following two functions:

```
template<class _T1, class _T2> constexpr bool 
std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
     operator<(const pair<_T1, _T2>& __x, const pair<_T1, _T2>& __y)
```

The compiler thought that maybe you meant to call them, you know maybe you made a typo or something. The compiler also told you where are they located:

```
C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_pair.h:369:5: note:
```

The middle part of the message also tells you how did the compiler find them, because they are included in your `main.cpp` through: ( read from bottom to top)

```
In file included from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/ios:40,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/ostream:38,
                 from C:/Program Files/Haskell 
Platform/8.2.2/mingw/include/c++/6.2.0/iostream:39,
```

These files are some reason located inside Haskell directory, that's all.

Error messages in C++ are sometimes long (especially with templates), but if you learn to read them carefully you should always have enough information to fix your code or atleast see where's the problem.